# Does the definition of primitive recursion depend on compare function and precedent function?

Tags: recursion

The primitive recursion is defined as following:

```
Given functions h,mapping from N+2 integers to 1 integer; and function g, mapping from N integers 
to 1 integer. we can define a new function f recursively.
f(0,y)=g(y)
f(x+1,y)=h(x,f(x,y),y)
```

If we have a machine to execute function f, then should the machine know whether the input parameter is 0? Does this imply a compare function is necessary?

And if the parameter is not 0, should the machine know how to get x from (x+1)? Does this imply a precedent function is necessary?

However from this [document](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cdm/pdf/PrimRec-6up.pdf), compare function and precedent function are both defined using primitive recursion.Why is this happening, did I miss some point?

Comment: The citation you've provided is a *formal definition*. It says nothing about implementation or machine which runs an implementation.

Comment: So how can we get x from x+1 if without precedent function or subtraction function? when we wrote f(x+1,y)=h(x,f(x,y),y), did we use precedent or subtraction implicitly?

Comment: Yes, this definition builds upon the [axioms for natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation), which include the existence of *successor function*. *Predecessor operation* may be defined formally based on successor function, for every number except zero.